# How can I use replace method to rewrite a url path?

Tags: javascript, regex

My project is using local server proxy. It proxys an api to my local file path by using regex.

Here is my scene:

My local http request is '/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123' and it will finally find the json file name of 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'.

Precondition: only the path begins with '/api' should be rewritten And the api path is uncertain.

Realizing a 'myRegex' to satisfy the three examples below:

example 1

```js
'/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123'.replace(myRegex, 'app/data/$1.json')
```

wanted: 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'

example 2

```js
'/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar'.replace(myRegex, 'app/data/$1.json')
```

wanted: 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'

example 3

```js
'/api/yt/order/export?id=1212'.replace(myRegex, 'app/data/$1.json')
```

wanted: 'app/data/yt/order/export.json'

I can only use replace method, help me to realize a 'myRegex' to solve it. My difficulty is the query parameters may not existing.

Comment: Consider using new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

Comment: I can't do it. Because the developing cli only exploses the interface of regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)[^?]?.*/
```

Made the queryparam '?' optional.

I checked this in jsfiddle.net

```
console.log('/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123'.replace(/.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)[^?]?.*/, 'app/data/$1.json'))  

console.log('/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar'.replace(/.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)[^?]?.*/, 'app/data/$1.json'))
```

Demo and explanation here:
https://regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/10
regex101.com/r/HBvG3K/11

Updated as per the request in the chat

```
\/api\/([\w\-\/]+).*
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy exapmle 2.

Comment: I am checking the other example too.

Comment: After mading the queryparam '?' optional  doesn't satisfy exapmle 1.console.log('/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpmCode=123213'.replace(/.*?(?!.*\/)(.*)\??.*/, 'app/data/$1.json'))

Comment: `console.log('/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123'.replace(/.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)[^?]?.*/, 'app/data/$1.json')) 

console.log('/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar'.replace(/.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)[^?]?.*/, 'app/data/$1.json')) `

Both works now. I tested in jsfiddle.net. Can you also try it and confirm so that I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much. Could u explan the regex to me? I don't understand  '.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)'

Comment: By the way, I just want to rewrite the path begins with '/api'

Comment: `'.*?(?!.*\/)([\w\-]+)'` - We are doing negative lookahead for '/' character meaning to find the last position of '/' character and after that [\w\-] to match the characters or '-' which comes after last '/' character. If the characters coming after last '/' character contains any other characters then you can add it to `[\w\-]` in order to properly match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219728/discussion-between-jon003-and-rootkonda).

Answer (score 0):

since this task does not require an approach that takes global or multiline flags into account, a simple regex like [`(/\/api\/([^?#]+)[?#]*.*/)`](https://regex101.com/r/3mab2d/1) already should be sufficient / reliable enough ... see tests below that meet the OP's requirement(s) ...

```js
// see also: [https://regex101.com/r/3mab2d/1]

const regXReplacePath = (/\/api\/([^?#]+)[?#]*.*/);


// example 1
// :: '/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123'
// => 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'

console.log(
  '/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar?bpm=123'.replace(

    regXReplacePath,
    'app/data/$1.json'

  ) === 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'
);


// example 2
// :: '/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar'
// => 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'

console.log(
  '/api/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar'.replace(

    regXReplacePath,
    'app/data/$1.json'

  ) === 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'
);


// example 3
// :: '/api/yt/order/export?id=1212'
// => 'app/data/bpm/fetch-action-progress-bar.json'

console.log(
  '/api/yt/order/export?id=1212'.replace(

    regXReplacePath,
    'app/data/$1.json'

  ) === 'app/data/yt/order/export.json'
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```